# Azure SQL - How to remove attribute text from output

Tags: sql, json, azure

I am trying to remove the "attribute" from the output of Azure SQL for json path.

Consider the below test data:

```
create table test (country varchar(50), city varchar(50));

insert into test values ('US', 'New York');
insert into test values ('US', 'Las Vegas');
insert into test values ('France', 'Paris');
insert into test values ('Canada', 'Toranto');
insert into test values ('Canada', 'Vancouver');
```

The below SQL when run gives the output shown:

```
select DISTINCT country, (select city 
                   from test b
                  where b.country=a.country
                   for json path
                ) as city 
from test a 
for json path;
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "country": "Canada",
        "city": [
            {
                "city": "Toranto"
            },
            {
                "city": "Vancouver"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "France",
        "city": [
            {
                "city": "Paris"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "US",
        "city": [
            {
                "city": "New York"
            },
            {
                "city": "Las Vegas"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

However, I would like the output to be of the below form i.e. city attribute removed from the output and the values as an array

```
[
    {
        "country": "Canada",
        "city": [
              "Toranto"
            , "Vancouver"

        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "France",
        "city": [
                "Paris"
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "US",
        "city": [
            "New York"
            ,"Las Vegas"
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following works for you:

```
select DISTINCT country as country,json_query((select CONCAT('[','"', STRING_AGG(city, '","'), '"',']') 
                   from test b
                   where b.country=a.country
                )) as city 
from test a 
for json path
```

Example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c3e597f425e73b86b629c16d55ddc266).